# Childrens Horror Anthology 1990's

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a couple of horror anthology books as a kid (1998-2001 approx.) but for the life of me, I cannot remember the titles. I remember several of the stories though.

There was one where there's a town with a tradition of ringing a bell every year to commemorate a centuries-old attack by pirates but a group of kids steal the bell as a joke only for the ghosts of the pirates to attack the town.

A group of kids sneak into the Egyptian wing of the museum after hours and accidentally wake a mummy. The story ends with the mummy looking out on the town at sunrise.

Some kids find a hidden cave outside their town and inside is a spring that turns anyone who drinks from it invisible. They discover that the cave is also home to giant invisible bats that can now escape into the world.

If anyone recognizes these or can point me in the right direction I would be so grateful. It's been driving me nuts for years.
Also none of these were Goosbumps books. They were collections of short stories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scary Stories for Sleep-overs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scary_Stories_for_Sleep-overs) sounds like it.

According to [a blog review](http://www.gnarlybookreviews.com/2014/11/super-scary-stories-for-sleep-overs.html) the stories you described are:

1st: "A Dead Man's Chest"

2nd:"Flesh and Blood"

3rd: "Cave Dwellers"